# Getting error:-"TypeError: no numeric data to plot" even while following a tutorial exactly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to follow a youtube machine learning tutorial from sentdex.[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLVMqwpOLPk&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v&index=5)

When I try to plot the graph using

```
df['forecast'].plot()
```

I get the error -**TypeError: no numeric data to plot**

However,

```
df['Adj. Close'].plot()
```

renders perfectly.

My code is-

```
'''
    
    df=quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
    
    df=df[['Adj. Open', 'Adj. High', 'Adj. Low', 'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume']]
    
    df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] *100
    
    df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] *100
    
    forecast_col='Adj. Close'
    df.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)
    forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))
    print(len(df) ,forecast_out)
    df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
    X=np.array(df.drop(['label'], axis=1 ))
    X=preprocessing.scale(X)
    X=X[:-forecast_out]
    X_lately=X[-forecast_out:]
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    y=np.array(df[['label']])
    algo=LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
    
    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=.2)
    algo.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred =algo.predict(X_lately)
    
    df['forecast']=np.nan
    last_date=df.iloc[-1].name 
    last_unix=last_date.timestamp()
    one_day = 86400
    next_unix = last_unix +one_day
    
    for i in y_pred:
        next_date =datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_unix)
        next_unix += one_day
        df.loc[next_date]= [np.NaN for _ in range(len(df.columns)-1)] + [i]  
    df['Adj. Close'].plot()
    df['forecast'].plot()   
    plt.show()   
    
    '''
```

Comment: what does `print(df['forecast'])` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,Found my mistake-

```
y=np.array(df['label'])
```

instead of

```
y=np.array(df[['label']])
```

Found it 5 minutes after posting this question,while I was banging my head on wall for literally hours because of this.